# Convert content:// to File://

Tags: android, android-intent

I want to  know how we can convert content:// to file://. In my application I implement custom Content Provider and now I want to convert content: // to file://.

Code:

**content://com.abc.provider.local.file/mail/attachment/1.jpg** want to convert to file://

```
String contentPath = LocalFileProvider.MAIL_FILE_URI + picture.getFileName(); 
Uri photoPath = Uri.parse(contentPath);
```

Comment: did you use a URI? share your code

Comment: String contentPath = LocalFileProvider.MAIL_FILE_URI
      + picture.getFileName(); and Uri photoPath = Uri.parse(contentPath); in above syntax LocalFileProvider is my custom content provider and MaIL_FILE_URL is mail\attachement and photoPath is my URI which i want to convert to file://

Comment: what's wrong with content:// ?

Comment: It not work on some devices so i want to use file://

Answer (score 1):

```
public String getRealPathFromURI(Uri contentUri) {
        String[] proj = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
        Cursor cursor = managedQuery(contentUri, proj, null, null, null);
        int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        return cursor.getString(column_index);
    }
```

Comment: Nirav, I tried above code but in this cursor is null so it not give me the file path

Comment: no, i not given write permission to it. Does this reason cursor return null?

Comment: Nirav, I give the read external storage permission to my application but it give null pointerexception on this line   int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);